# While converting a Drupal 6 theme to Drupal 7, is there a work-around for theme_blocks()?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7, theming

I currently use `theme_blocks()` in a base theme for Drupal 6, and I have had difficulty converting my theme to Drupal 7 because `theme_blocks()` is not used in Drupal 7. The below code is a simple implementation of the function and how I currently use it in Drupal 6:

```
/* Implementation of theme_blocks() */
function theme_blocks($region) {
  var output = '';
  if ($list = block_list($region)) {
    //cycle through all blocks in a region
    foreach ($list as $key => $block) {
      //test each block for a given condition
      if ($block->delta == 1) {
        output = /* make some changes */
      }
      else {
        output = /* theme per usual */
      }
    }
  }

  return $output;
}
```

So, essentially I was just using `theme_blocks()` to cycle through all blocks in a region, targeting a specific block, and change up a few things. The problem is that `theme_blocks()` is not anymore used in Drupal 7.

Is there a way to target specific block/blocks in a given region, and dynamically make changes based on a theme setting in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [theme_blocks()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_blocks/6) theme function (it is not a hook) is not used anymore in Drupal 7. If you need to alter how a block is rendered you need to implement a preprocess function for the block template file (`THEMENAME_preprocess_block()`; see the documentation for [template_preprocess_block()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7)) or use the [block.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.tpl.php/7) template file in your theme.

Keep in mind that the logic part should go in the preprocess function, and the rendering code should go in the template file.